# BigQuery Results in Two Rows - Need to be on the same row

Tags: google-bigquery, count, case

I have hit a wall.  I am attempting to get a count of accounts, but also separate this count by account_type.  I did try COUNT and COUNTIF first, but that did not work.  I then did a CASE statement and did get results.  But it is separating the rows when I need the results on the same row.  I need the top5 and can't do that if they are on separate rows.

Thoughts?

I tried adding a case statement.  I did get results, but now on separate rows.  I need the results on the same row.

Sample query - I only added the account number line on the bottom to test the query to see if I can get it on one row.

```
SELECT distinct acc3.country,
acc1.enroller_account_number,
acc3.first_name,
acc3.last_name,


--count(distinct acc1.account_number) as total_enrollments,
case when acc1.account_type = 'Preferred Customer' then count( 
distinct acc1.account_number) END as total_preferred_customers,
case when acc1.account_type = 'Consultant' then count( distinct 
acc1.account_number) END as total_consultants

FROM 'table1' acc1
left join 'table1' acc2 on acc1.account_number = acc2.account_number
left join 'table1' acc3 on acc1.enroller_account_number = 
acc3.account_number

where acc2.enrollment_period_id = 202307
and acc1.enroller_account_number = '011111111'
and acc1.is_current=1
```

group by 1, 2, 3, 4, acc1.account_type
--order by total_enrollments desc limit 5

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use a `GROUP BY` statement:

```
SELECT account_type, COUNT(account) AS cnt
FROM your_table
GROUP BY account_type
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 5  -- top 5
```

If this is not what you need, please add a code sample, input data and what you are expecting as an output.